# Setting outlook.attachment = Mail item attachment

Tags: vba, attachment, mailitem

I am trying to write a script that saves attachments to a directory.  When I run it, I get an error message "type mismatch" and the line `Set olAtt = olMi.Attachments`  is highlighted.  Could someone advise?

```
Sub SaveAttachments()

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNs As Namespace
Dim Fldr As MAPIFolder
Dim MoveToFldr As MAPIFolder
Dim olMi As Outlook.MailItem
Dim olAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim MyPath As String
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim filesavename As String

Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Fldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set MoveToFldr = Fldr.Folders("Survey")
MyPath = "C:\Users\temp"


For i = (Fldr.Items.Count - 150) To Fldr.Items.Count 

    Set olMi = Fldr.Items(i)
    If InStr(1, olMi.Subject, "Survey") > 0 Then
        j = olMi.Attachments.Count
        Set olAtt = olMi.Attachments
        filesavename = MyPath & olAtt.Filename
        olAtt.SaveAsFile filesavename

        olMi.Save
        olMi.Move MoveToFldr

    End If
Next i

Set olAtt = Nothing
Set olMi = Nothing
Set Fldr = Nothing
Set MoveToFldr = Nothing
Set olNs = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

`olAtt` is declared as a `Outlook.Attachment` (singular).

`olMi.Attachments` is a collection of attachments.